# Show Triangular tag on layout

Tags: android, kotlin

[How to add the trianle shape with corner on layout like popular.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt91W.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the Popular text as an image view or You can use this library to display the text from TextView

You can modify the properties like corner,labelPadding,primaryText,primaryTextColor

https://github.com/shts/TriangleLabelView